# Critical values of $f(x) = \sin 2x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Given the curve $f(x)= \sin 2x$, find the critical points and the intervals where $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing.

My workings till where I get confused -

$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (\sin 2x) = 2\cos 2x$

Set $f'(x) = 0$

$2\cos 2x= 0$

Why the next step for this is -

$2x = \cos^{-1} 0$

And why does this situation have $2$ $x$ values?

I will never understand the $4$ quadrant rules.

Is there a fixed way that I can memorise? Like, e.g., is the cos/tan/sin of this angle lower than this particular value, then there are $2$ critical points? Thanks a lot! I really need to understand this.

Comment: you should get all the points where $ cos(2x)=0$ and remember that the $ cos(2x) $ has a period of $ \pi$ i will give you a value $ x= \pi /4 +\pi n 4 for every intenger 'n' now try more points :D

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is plot the graph so you can visualise what is happening. We know what the graph of $\sin(x)$ looks like, so we note that the frequency is doubled for $\sin(2x)$, so its period is $\pi$. 
[image]

As it's a periodic function with period $\pi$ we see that there's an infinite amount of critical points. As you've done, differentiating we get

$$\cos(2x) = 0 \implies 2x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi, \qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}\\\implies x = \frac{1}{2}\left(n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}\right), \qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

It is also obvious to note the increasing and decreasing intervals of the function after graphing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the equation $\cos(2x) = 0$.  Since $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$, we have 
$$\cos(2x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

When does $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$?

Consider the diagram below:

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Since the cosine of an angle in standard position (initial side on the positive $x$-axis and vertex at the origin) is the $x$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle, two angles have the same cosine if the $x$-coordinates of the points where their terminal sides intersect the unit circle are the same.  By symmetry, $\cos\theta = \cos(-\theta)$.  Any angle coterminal with $\theta$ or $-\theta$ will also have the same cosine.  Hence, 
$$\cos\theta = \cos\varphi \iff \varphi = \pm \theta + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Since we have 
$$\cos(2x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
we may conclude that 
$$2x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Solving for $x$ yields
$$x = \pm \frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$